# AS or not to AS, queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly new to PHP/MySql and using queries in general. I was just wondering if there's any benefit to using "AS" in a query other than trying to make it look cleaner? Does it speed up the query at all? I probably could have figured this out by a google search but I wanted to ask my first question and see how this works. I WILL select an answer (unlike some people...)

with:

```
SELECT
news.id as id
news.name as name
FROM news
```

without:

```
SELECT
news.id
news.name
FROM news
```

A more complex example from a many-to-many relationship tutorial I found:

```
SELECT
c.name,
cf.title
FROM celebrities AS c
JOIN (
    SELECT
    icf.c_id,
    icf.f_id,
    f.title
    FROM int_cf AS icf
    JOIN films AS f
    ON icf.f_id = f.f_id
) AS cf
ON c.c_id = cf.c_id
ORDER BY c.c_id ASC
```

Comment: Amazing how well this works! I had excellent answers immediately! It's like I'm living in the future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to use it if you know there will be no conflicts with other columns. There are no differences in performance, but it does change the name of the output column. It's really useful for when you construct dynamic selects. So for instance, if you had a `first_name` and a `last_name` field, you could use the CONCAT function to do:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS name FROM whatever
```

Furthermore, the AS operator works when defining sub-query tables, as you showed in that JOIN. Without that AS, you wouldn't be able to reference that table in the ON clause or the SELECT fields.

Comment: @zeMinimalis: it's not about `CONCAT` specifically, but about any expressions

Comment: Right, I meant I hadn't thought about the benefits when using expressions in general.

Answer (score 3):

1) No, it doesn't affect performance one way or the other

2) As far as readability of the SQL Query, it's just a matter of preference

3) It does affect the readability of the output (it changes the column headers)

Answer (score 2):

Only with regards to ambiguity & reserved words. It does not affect performance. Ambiguity refers to two columns with the same names coming from separate tables. Other RDBMS's will slap you for this. Reserved words refers to system words that must either be escaped using backticks or aliased.

With subqueries, aliased columns may not be derived past the child level.

Comment: **R** elational **D** ata **B** ase **M** anagement **S** ystems.

Answer (score 1):

Speed of query execution when you use aliases ("AS" keyword) and when you dont use them is the same. Reasons for using them:

- it makes it easier to work with databases if you have very long or complex table names or column names:

> ```
> SELECT c.Construction_ID, c.Name, c.Price 
> FROM Constructions c LEFT JOIN 
> Constructions_Orders co ON c.Construction_ID = co.Construction_ID
> WHERE c.OrderID='1' AND c.Name='ConstructionName'
> ```

However, it changes output columns names, take it into account too (makes it harder for person who is reading code).

- Aliases are useful for creating dynamic selects:

> ```
> mysql> SELECT CONCAT(id, name, work_date) as profile
>     -> FROM employee_tbl;
> +-----------------------------+
> | profile                     |
> +-----------------------------+
> | 1John2007-01-24             |
> | 2Ram2007-05-27              |
> | 3Jack2007-05-06             |
> | 3Jack2007-04-06             |
> | 4Jill2007-04-06             |
> | 5Zara2007-06-06             |
> | 5Zara2007-02-06             |
> +-----------------------------+
> 7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
> ```